# How to write an interactive process in Rust?

Tags: rust

If I am to fork a new process to run /bin/sh (or any other interactive commands e.g. fdisk); How can I pipe the system stdin to the process to make it an interactive shell, while printing out stdout?

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::io::{self, Write};

let process = Command::new("/bin/sh").spawn();
    
match process.spawn() {
    Ok(child) => {
        if let Some(stdout) = child.stdout {
            let reader = BufReader::new(stdout);

            for line in reader.lines() {
                println!("{}", line.unwrap());
            }
        }
    }
    Err(e) => eprintln!("Err: {:?} ", e),
}
```

The goal is for the end-user to be able to interactively work with the newly forked process.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/#handling-io

Comment: .stdin() does not accept io::stdin()  as input. Is there anyway I can change io::stdin() to Stdio?

Comment: Note that to get _real_ interactive-shell behavior you need to emulate a TTY. That's a fair bit more work than what you get for free -- look at expect/pexpect/[empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) for examples of codebases that do that work. (Or, for a Rust example -- https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty being a terminal emulator, it'll have this work somewhere inside its codebase).